# InMemory database in Entity Framework Core missing method exception when adding range to context

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I have a peculiar problem. I want to test few services of my application, and one of them uses `identityDbContext` directly, so instead of mocking it, what is nearly impossible I have tried to use InMemoryDatabase. Context is being created without any issues, but when I try to add something to Dbsets it throws error:

> System.MissingMethodException: "Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<System.__Canon,System.Object>>)'."

on this part of code - to be exact on `OnModelCreating` line.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<UserCurrency>()
            .HasKey(uc => new { uc.CurrencyId, uc.UserId });
}
```

Error happens on the before last line with

```
context.AddRange(testUser, testUserCurrency, testCurrency);

private DBContext CreateInMemoryDBContext()
{
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>()
              .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
              .Options;

        var context = new DBContext(options);

        User testUser = new User()
        {
            UserName = "Mark",
            Id = "1",
            UserFavoriteCurrencies = new List<UserCurrency>()
        };
        UserCurrency testUserCurrency = new UserCurrency()
        {
            CurrencyId = 1,
            Currency = null,
            UserId = testUser.Id,
            User = testUser,
        };

        Currency testCurrency = new Currency()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "USD",
            FavoritedByUsers = new List<UserCurrency> { testUserCurrency }
        };

        context.AddRange(testUser, testUserCurrency, testCurrency);

        return context;
}
```

This is my csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0"                 />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="3.1.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.6.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="MockQueryable.Core" Version="3.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="MockQueryable.Moq" Version="3.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.14.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="4.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.2">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers;         buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
      </ItemGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\BusinessLogic\BusinessLogic.csproj" />
      </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have already tried to make changes to package versions - if I lower in memory it doesn't work at all. What could be the problem?

PS. This is  part of the csproj from referenced BusinessLogic project.

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Loggly" Version="5.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="SharpZipLib" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="X.PagedList" Version="7.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="X.PagedList.Mvc.Core" Version="7.6.0" />
```

Comment: Try changing `context.AddRange(testUser, testUserCurrency, testCurrency);` -> `context.AddRange(testUser)`

Comment: Checked, changed even to: `context.Users.Add(testUser);
            context.UsersCurrencies.Add(testUserCurrency);
            context.SaveChanges();`   No difference. From what I can see Model and ChangeTracker inside of the context throw missing method exception